# Base Class Function Not Calling Derived Class Function

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions

I've looked around at multiple questions on this topic on SO as well as several references and have not seen this issue come up anywhere.

When my instance of `Derived` calls `Base::GetValue()` (which calls the `virtual` `doGetValue()`, defined in `Derived` and in `Base`), `Base::doGetValue()` is called instead of `Derived::doGetValue()`. Why is that and what do I need to do differently?

Is it because `Derived::doGetValue()` is `private` instead of `protected`? That seems to me to be the most likely explanation, but I haven't seen that explicitly stated anywhere that I've looked so far.

[Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da2f1fa0f33a2d20) is my code on coliru.

Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
private:
    virtual string      doGetname(  ) const { return "Base"; };

protected:
    virtual void        doGetValue( map<string,string> &ds, const bool include ) const;
    inline void         doGetValue( map<string,string> &ds ) const { doGetValue(ds, true); };

public:
    string              GetValue(  ) const;
    string              GetName(  ) const { return doGetname(); };
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    virtual void        doGetValue( map<string,string> &ds ) const;
    virtual string      doGetname(  ) const { return "Derived"; };
};

struct generate_value_from_map : std::unary_function<void, void>
{
    generate_value_from_map( string *_val, const string assignment = "  " ):val(_val)
    {
        count = 0;
        insert = (*_val);
        first = "(";
        second = ") "+assignment+" (";
    }
    void operator() (pair<const string,string> &i)
    {
        first += ( count > 0 ? "," : "" ) + i.first;
        second += ( count > 0 ? "," : "" ) + i.second;

        (*val) = insert + first + second + ")";

        ++count;
    }

private:
    int count;
    string *val;
    string insert;
    string first;
    string second;
};

string  Base::GetValue(  ) const
{
    string ret_val = "name is: " + GetName() + " \n";
    map<string,string> ret_map;
    this->doGetValue(ret_map);
    for_each(ret_map.begin(), ret_map.end(), generate_value_from_map(&ret_val));
    return ret_val;
}

void  Base::doGetValue( map<string,string> &ds, const bool include ) const
{
    //base implementation
    //fills ds with values from Base
    ds["type"] = "Base";
    ds["id"] = "Id";
}

void  Derived::doGetValue( map<string,string> &ds ) const
{
    Base::doGetValue( ds );
    //derived implementation
    //fills ds with values from Derived
    ds["type"] = "Derived";
    ds["name"] = "Name";
}

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Derived> obj ( new Derived() );

    string val = obj->GetValue();

    cout << val;

    //do stuff with val
}
```

I tried to include all the specifics of my issue, excluding some of the delphi-inherited features of my compiler (RAD Studio XE4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definitions of doGetValue are different between base and derived.

Base:

```
virtual void        doGetValue( map<string,string> &ds, const bool include ) const;
inline void         doGetValue( map<string,string> &ds ) const { doGetValue(ds, true); };
```

Derived:

```
virtual void        doGetValue( map<string,string> &ds ) const;
```

In the base the function is not virtual.

Comment: So I need the overloaded `doGetValue(...)` to be `virtual inline` instead of just `inline`?

Comment: Inline is meaningless in virtual functions. you can drop it. it must be virtual in your example.

Comment: Thanks, that takes care of it.